# How to use scrapy.Request to load an element from another page into an item

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I've created a web scraper using Scrapy that is able to scrape elements from each ticket from this [website](http://www.vividseats.com/concerts/awolnation-tickets.html) but cannot scrape the ticket price since it isn't available on the page. When I try to request the next page to scrape the price, I am unable to and get the error: exceptions.TypeError: 'XPathItemLoader' object has no attribute '**getitem**'. I have only been able to scrape any elements using item loaders so that's what I am currently using and I'm not exactly sure the correct procedure for passing scraped elements on another page to the item loader ( I have seen one way to do it with the item data type but it didn't apply here). I think I possibly could have been having problems extracting elements into an item object because I am pipelining into a database, but I'm not sure exactly. If the code I post below could be modified in order to properly crawl to the next page, scrape the price, and add it to the item loader, I think the problem should be solved. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
 class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [416]
    name = 'comparator'
    allowed_domains = ["www.vividseats.com"]
    start_urls = [vs_url]
    tickets_list_xpath = './/*[@itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"]'
    def parse_price(self, response):
        #First attempt at trying to load price into item loader
        loader.add_xpath('ticketPrice' , '//*[@class="eventTickets lastChild"]/div/div/@data-origin-price')
        print 'ticket price'
    def parse(self, response):
        selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        # iterate over tickets
        for ticket in selector.select(self.tickets_list_xpath):

            loader = XPathItemLoader(ComparatorItem(), selector=ticket)
            # define loader
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
            loader.default_output_processor = Join()
            # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader

            loader.add_xpath('eventName' , './/*[@class="productionsEvent"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventLocation' , './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "name"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('ticketsLink' , './/*/td[3]/a/@href')
            loader.add_xpath('eventDate' , './/*[@class = "productionsDate"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventCity' , './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "address"]/span[@itemprop  = "addressLocality"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventState' , './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "address"]/span[@itemprop  = "addressRegion"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventTime' , './/*[@class = "productionsTime"]/text()')

            ticketsURL = "concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets/" + bandname + "-" + loader["ticketsLink"]
            request = scrapy.Request(ticketsURL , callback = self.parse_price)
            yield loader.load_item()
```

Comment: @loremlpsum: is your problem solved?  I have a similar problem.  Even after reading this post very carefully, I still can not figure out the problem.  Please kindly shed some lights [on my poster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667885/scrapy-can-not-scrape-a-second-page-using-itemloader).

Comment: @loremlpsum1771: I solved my problem completely. I learned good stuff from your post.  Feel free to visit my post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667885/solved-with-updated-codes-scrapy-can-not-scrape-a-second-page-using-itemloader)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Key things to fix:

- to get the value from an item loader, use [`get_output_value()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.loader.ItemLoader.get_output_value), replace:

  ```
  loader["ticketsLink"]
  ```

  with:

  ```
  loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
  ```
- you need to pass the `loader` inside the `meta` of the request and yield/return the loaded item there
- when constructing the URL to get the price, use [`urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) to join the relative part with the current URL

Here is the fixed version:

```
from urlparse import urljoin
# other imports

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [416]
    name = 'comparator'
    allowed_domains = ["www.vividseats.com"]
    start_urls = [vs_url]
    tickets_list_xpath = './/*[@itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"]'
    def parse_price(self, response):
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        loader.add_xpath('ticketPrice' , '//*[@class="eventTickets lastChild"]/div/div/@data-origin-price')
        return loader.load_item()

    def parse(self, response):
        selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        # iterate over tickets
        for ticket in selector.select(self.tickets_list_xpath):

            loader = XPathItemLoader(ComparatorItem(), selector=ticket)
            # define loader
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
            loader.default_output_processor = Join()
            # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader

            loader.add_xpath('eventName' , './/*[@class="productionsEvent"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventLocation' , './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "name"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('ticketsLink' , './/*/td[3]/a/@href')
            loader.add_xpath('eventDate' , './/*[@class = "productionsDate"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventCity' , './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "address"]/span[@itemprop  = "addressLocality"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventState' , './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "address"]/span[@itemprop  = "addressRegion"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventTime' , './/*[@class = "productionsTime"]/text()')

            ticketsURL = "concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets/" + bandname + "-" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            ticketsURL = urljoin(response.url, ticketsURL)
            yield scrapy.Request(ticketsURL, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_price)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! I think the remaining problem is with the get_value() function because I'm getting the error:  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 61, in _set_url raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)exceptions.ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: concerts/awolnation-tickets/awolnation-ticketsLink
Do you know what is causing this?

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 sure, I've updated the answer. Check it out.

Comment: it seems like the url is being joined properly; however, the value of loader["ticketsLink"] is not being retrieved as the get request for that link is <GET http://www.vividseats.com/concerts/concerts/awolnation-tickets/awolnation-ticketsLink>. So its just taking the literal string of ticketsLink.  Can the element not be extracted from the loader because its being done within the loop? Thanks!

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 sorry, my bad, you need to use `get_output_value` instead of `get_value` :)

Comment: I actually just tried that before you replied lol : ticketsURL = "concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets/" + bandname + "-" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink") and I'm getting this error:  DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET http://www.vividseats.com/concerts/concerts/awolnation-tickets/awolnation-> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
Thanks for all of the help btw!

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 okay, this is a different problem. Show the complete code you have so far. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82390/discussion-between-loremipsum1771-and-alecxe).

Answer (score 1):

I have an exact problem and solved it in another post.  I put my code here to share: (my original post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667885/solved-with-updated-codes-scrapy-can-not-scrape-a-second-page-using-itemloader))

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy import Request
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from CAPjobs.items import CAPjobsItem 
from CAPjobs.items import CAPjobsItemLoader

class CAPjobSpider(Spider):
    name = "naturejob3"
    download_delay = 2
    #allowed_domains = ["nature.com/naturejobs/"]
    start_urls = [
"http://www.nature.com/naturejobs/science/jobs?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=pathologist&where=&commit=Find+Jobs"]

    def parse_subpage(self, response):
        il = response.meta['il']
        location = response.xpath('//div[@id="extranav"]//ul[@class="job-addresses"]/li/text()').extract()
        il.add_value('loc_pj', location)  
        yield il.load_item()

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        sites = hxs.xpath('//div[@class="job-details"]')    

        for site in sites:

            il = CAPjobsItemLoader(CAPjobsItem(), selector = site) 
            il.add_xpath('title', 'h3/a/text()')
            il.add_xpath('post_date', 'normalize-space(ul/li[@class="when"]/text())')
            il.add_xpath('web_url', 'concat("http://www.nature.com", h3/a/@href)')
            url = il.get_output_value('web_url')
            yield Request(url, meta={'il': il}, callback=self.parse_subpage)
```