# Scrapy can not scrape a second page using itemloader

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

Update: 7/29, 9:29pm: After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31215542/how-to-use-scrapy-request-to-load-an-element-from-another-page-into-an-item), I updated my code.

UPDATE: 7/28/15, at 7:35pm, following Martin's suggestion, the message changed, but still no listing of items or writing to database.

ORIGINAL: I can successfully scrape a single page (the base page).  Now I tried to scrape one of the items from another url found from the "base" page, using Request and callback command.  But it does not work.  The spider is here:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy import Request
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from CAPjobs.items import CAPjobsItem 
from CAPjobs.items import CAPjobsItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import MapCompose, Join

class CAPjobSpider(Spider):
    name = "naturejob3"
    download_delay = 2
    #allowed_domains = ["nature.com/naturejobs/"]
    start_urls = [
    "http://www.nature.com/naturejobs/science/jobs?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=pathologist&where=&commit=Find+Jobs"]

    def parse_subpage(self, response):
        il = response.meta['il']
        il.add_xpath('loc_pj', '//div[@id="extranav"]/div/dl/dd[2]/ul/li/text()')  
        yield il.load_item()

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        sites = hxs.xpath('//div[@class="job-details"]')    

        for site in sites:

            il = CAPjobsItemLoader(CAPjobsItem(), selector = site) 
            il.add_xpath('title', 'h3/a/text()')
            il.add_xpath('post_date', 'normalize-space(ul/li[@class="when"]/text())')
            il.add_xpath('web_url', 'concat("http://www.nature.com", h3/a/@href)')
            url = il.get_output_value('web_url')
            yield Request(url, meta={'il': il}, callback=self.parse_subpage)
```

Now the scraping is partially functioning, but no `loc_pj` item: (UPDATE on 7/29, 7:35pm)

```
2015-07-29 21:28:24 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.nature.com/naturejobs/science/jobs/535683-assistant-associate-full-hs-clinical-clin-x-anatomic-pathology-cytopathology-11-000>
{'post_date': u'21 days ago',
'title': u'Assistant, Associate, Full (HS Clinical, Clin X) - Anatomic Pathology/Cytopathology (11-000)',
'web_url': u'http://www.nature.com/naturejobs/science/jobs/535683-assistant-associate-full-hs-clinical-clin-x-anatomic-pathology-cytopathology-11-000'}
```

Comment: I still don't understand why in `parse_subpage` that `il.add_xpath` does not work.  I have to create a variable of `location` and use `xpath().extract()` first and then use `il.add_value`.  Just curious.

Comment: @LeamAWK hey sir can you answer my question too?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517655/scrapping-website-which-having-page

Comment: I've rollback your replacement of the question by a solution. Please find [your solution in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/c2f396b5-fbd5-4ca1-81b8-213bee1af248/view-source) and post it as an answer of its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize the `ItemLoader` like so:

```
il = CAPjobsItemLoader(CAPjobsItem, sites)
```

In the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#using-item-loaders-to-populate-items) it is done like so:

```
l = ItemLoader(item=Product(), response=response)
```

So I think you're missing parentheses at the `CAPjobsItem` and your line should read:

```
il = CAPjobsItemLoader(CAPjobsItem(), sites)
```

Comment: Will give it a try after getting home. Thanks

Comment: after changing to `CAPjobsItem()`, the message (without the same "ERROR") changed to something different (See above update, due to the limitation of comment length).  But I don't get items listed out.

Comment: Please remove the path from the allowed_domains statement. Or comment out to test if your requests get filtered without that statement.

Comment: long story short: after I remove the `allowed_domains`, the scraping is partially functioning, but the `loc_pj` item didn't show up in the list. (see the updated code and log messages above.)  Thanks a lot!

Comment: After fixing the xpath for `loc_pj` and breaking `add_xpath` to two-line codes as `location = response.xpath('//div[@id="extranav"]//ul[@class="job-addresses"]/li/text()').extract()
     il.add_value('loc_pj', location)` (even though I don't know why it works), the problem was solved.  The codes was updated also.  Thanks  a lot!